# Nested collection view in table view is better or multiple collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have to showcase some image with a little information like title and subtitle which will be horizontally swipeable. Basically, it will be like Airbnb app which shows the `category and elements in it with horizontal swipe`. The only difference is that in my case number of category(row) is fixed, `which is 2`. DataSource is same for both rows. I have two approach first is using `two CollectionView` and second one is by using `a TableView and nesting the CollectionView inside tableview cell`. Googled and get only the implementation part for both approach not the comparison or use cases for the approach. So my question here is, which process should I follow and why?

Comment: i think this repo will help you. https://github.com/ashfurrow/AFTabledCollectionView

Comment: You can add collectionview in tableview. Please check this.
https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/

Comment: @Jayesh: I want to know the better approach for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) Using nested Collection view will make the code complex.Generally used only when cannot be implementable using table view.

2) Table view is similar to collection view just that it can be scrollable vertical not horizontal. This make table view easy to implement.

3) In your case collection in table view will work great. Row is fixed in that case you can use static table view.